# Accessing controls contained in DataTemplates

Tags: .net, wpf, combobox

Given the following XAML:

```
  <ListView Name="selectedCallees" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=map, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window},
            Mode=OneWay}" Height="239" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,215,10,0" >
     <ListView.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter1" />
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
           <Style.Triggers>
              <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True">
                 <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
              </DataTrigger>
           </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
     </ListView.Resources>
     <ListView.View>
        <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="True" ColumnHeaderToolTip="Broadcast call targets">         
           <GridViewColumn Width="120">
              <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                 <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=extensions, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"
                              Width="105" IsEditable="True" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" BorderThickness="0" SelectedValue="------------"
                              SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Key, Mode=OneWay}" SelectionChanged="chooseExtension_SelectionChanged" >
                       <ComboBox.Resources>
                          <sys:Double x:Key="{x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}">15</sys:Double>
                       </ComboBox.Resources>
                    </ComboBox>
                 </DataTemplate>
              </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
           </GridViewColumn>  
           <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Value}" Header="Description" Width="305" />
           <GridViewColumn Header="" Width="30">
              <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                 <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Content="X" Height="21" Width="18" Click="Button_Click" Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}, Path=IsMouseOver, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter1}}" />
                 </DataTemplate>
              </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
           </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
     </ListView.View>      
  </ListView>
```

As noted in ComboBox.Resources I may set the SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey to some value.  What I'd like to do is set this to a custom when the Loaded event fires (handled by ComboBox_Loaded).

Is this possible, or is there another way to selectively make the ComboBox drop arrow disappear?

Comment: I don't see any problem with simply setting it in the `Loaded` event of the `ComboBox`. What happens when you do it that way?

Comment: I don't think you can directly set SystemParamaters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey because it's read-only.

Comment: Instead of trying to set the value directly, can you try adding the value to the `ComboBox.Resources` like you do in the XAML?

Comment: Originally that's what I was doing.  But by adding it to the ComboBox.Resources, it applies to all the combo boxes in that gridview column.  In my particular case, I'd want some of them to be set one way, and some set another way.  Hopefully this is possible.